# Configure/Install openssl for php on SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP3

Tags: php, ssl, openssl, suse

I am trying to get rid of this error when sending notifications using the ssl protocol in php code:

> "Failed to connect: 1976434032 Unable to find the socket transport
>   \"ssl\" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?"

**1**: The system is SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP3.

**2**: When doing this command `rpm -qa | grep ssl`, I get:

```
 - openssl-certs-1.97-0.3.1
 - openssl-0.9.8j-0.80.1
 - libopenssl0_9_8-0.9.8j-0.80.1
 - libopenssl0_9_8-32bit-0.9.8j-0.80.1
```

**3**: Inside the php.ini file, this line has been uncommented and apache has been restarted:

```
 - extension=php_openssl.dll
```

**4**: Looking at phpinfo, i have these settings:

```
 - Registered PHP Streams => php, file, glob, data, http, ftp  
 - Registered Stream Socket Transports => tcp, udp, unix, udg
 - Registered Stream Filters => string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk, convert.iconv.*
```

THIS SECTION DOES NOT APPEAR IN THE FILE:

```
 - openssl
 - OpenSSL support => enabled
 - OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
 - OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
```

According to these informations, it looks like openssl is not installed or configured properly. But I have no clue how to fix the issue.

What should i do to enable openssl in php to get rid of this message:

> "Failed to connect: 1976434032 Unable to find the socket transport
>   \"ssl\" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?"

Does anyone could help me?